# When I run in docker why localhost giving connection refused?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose, cassandra

This is my docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  zookeeper-1:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:latest
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
    ports:
      - 22181:2181

  kafka-1:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:latest
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper-1
    ports:
      - 29092:29092
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper-1:2181
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka-1:9092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:29092
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1

 cassandra:
   image: cassandra
   container_name: cassandra
   ports:
    - 9042:9042

 producer:
   image: spring/producer
   links:
    - cassandra
   depends_on:
    - cassandra
    - kafka-1
   restart: always
 consumer:
  image: spring/consumer
  links:
    - cassandra
  depends_on:
    - cassandra
    - kafka-1
  restart: always
```

When I run with first three service in docker (kafka zookeper and cassandra). I can reach with producer and consumer with intellj runner. But when I add docker compose file (producer and consumer) as a services and docker-compose up, producer and consumer services getting localhost:9042 Connection refused error.

Why I cannot reach to cassandra from producer and consumer when i run with Docker. What differences?
This is my producer application.yml

```
spring:
  kafka:
    producer:
      bootstrap-servers: localhost:29092
      key-serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.IntegerSerializer
      value-serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
      properties:
        acks: all
        retries: 10
    admin:
      properties:
        bootstrap.servers: localhost:29092
    template:
      default-topic: users-events
  data:
    cassandra:
      port: 9042
      keyspace-name: mykeyspace
      username: cassandra
      schema-action: create_if_not_exists
```

Comment: Are you sure that that all of your container running in same docker network?

Comment: Yes I tried that one but same result.